# How to concatenate all dataframe column into one column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, concatenation

I have a dataframe that looks roughly like:

```
           2020-01-01   2020-01-02   2020-01-03   2020-01-05
00:00:00     11             47          54           10 
01:00:00     12             49          46           22
...
23:00:00     15             34          22           40
```

Expected output...

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00   11
2020-01-01 01:00:00   12
...
2020-01-01 23:00:00   12
2020-01-02 00:00:00   47
2020-01-02 01:00:00   49
...
2020-01-01 23:00:00   34
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with convert index to column, then convert columns to datetimes and timedeltas and join together with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns:

```
df = df.reset_index().melt('index')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('variable')) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('index'))

#alternative with join strings
#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('variable') + ' ' + df.pop('index'))
print (df)
                     value
2020-01-01 00:00:00     11
2020-01-01 01:00:00     12
2020-01-01 23:00:00     15
2020-01-02 00:00:00     47
2020-01-02 01:00:00     49
2020-01-02 23:00:00     34
2020-01-03 00:00:00     54
2020-01-03 01:00:00     46
2020-01-03 23:00:00     22
2020-01-05 00:00:00     10
2020-01-05 01:00:00     22
2020-01-05 23:00:00     40
```

If `pop` is not used is necessary remove columns by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().melt('index')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['variable']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['index'])
df = df.drop(['index','variable'], axis=1)
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and join `MultiIndex` with `map` and convert to `DatetimeIndex`, output is `Series`:

```
s = df.unstack()
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index.map('{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format))
print (s)
2020-01-01 00:00:00    11
2020-01-01 01:00:00    12
2020-01-01 23:00:00    15
2020-01-02 00:00:00    47
2020-01-02 01:00:00    49
2020-01-02 23:00:00    34
2020-01-03 00:00:00    54
2020-01-03 01:00:00    46
2020-01-03 23:00:00    22
2020-01-05 00:00:00    10
2020-01-05 01:00:00    22
2020-01-05 23:00:00    40
dtype: int64
```

Comment: is it possible to create another column in the dataframe using the date in the index to show the day of the week?

Some thing like:
 

`2020-01-01 00:00:00     11                Monday`

Comment: @adi - Sure, what solution is used?

Comment: @adi - Use `df['day'] = df.index.day_name()`, [`DatetimeIndex.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day_name.html), if use last solution first is necesary `df = s.to_frame('val')`